# Database modelling of prizes table that allows customization per contest

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have the following problem modelling some database tables:

Let's say I have some contests (in a contests table, with a unique id for each one), and on each contest they give some prizes to the players. There are 3 prizes (gold, silver, bronze), each of them having a title, a logo image and maybe other data in the future.

However, on some contests (based on a contest id) I would like to be able to customize the logo or title of some of the prizes. If the prize is not customized, they would just have some default values.

Another requirement would be to be able to select all players that won the gold medal in any contest (basically ignore the customization)

My solutions so far are:

1. In the prizes table, besides the primary key add another key that is semi-unique. Although every customized gold medals have different primary keys, they would still share the same  semi-unique key (let's call it tag).
   This way, I am able to customize any column for the prizes but keep the ability to select all gold winners (using the common tag).
2. Split the prizes table in two: immutable data and mutable (customizable) data.
   This way, I can have a single unique primary key for the gold medal, but in the mutable data table that ID could be found in several rows. In this table the primary key would be a composite of prize id and contest id.

What solution do you like best in terms of performance and maybe flexibility in adding other information to the prizes?
Do you suggest another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suggesting a normalized table design.

Medal_Types

```
id | type 
-----------
1  | gold
2  | silver
3  | bronze
```

Contests

```
id | name      | date        | any-other-info
----------------------------------
1  | wimbeldon | 2013-07-05  | asdfsdf
1  | Devis cup | 2013-06-08  | sdfsd f
```

Prizes

```
id | contest_id | medal_type_id | logo | title
------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          |1              |abc    | abc
1  | 1          |2              |def    | winner2
1  | 1          |3              |ghi    | winner3
1  | 2          |1              |abc    | winner1
1  | 2          |2              |adf    | winner2
1  | 2          |3              |aad    | winner3
```

Comment: This pretty much resembles my second solution. I will go ahead and implement something like this. Thanks